# lightbox like script cross-domain iframe in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, cross-domain, lightbox

I'm looking for a lightbox-like script that can open a cross-domain iframe in Firefox.
I tried several scripts and Firebug says that it's not possible to get Window.frmResource property.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

http://fancybox.net/ - great little jQuery plugin that allows you to have an iFrame in a nice popup. Not sure what you are wanting to do with it after you've opened it though.